# Can the Apple ID be accessed?

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-sdk-4.1

When app's are installed from the App Store, the user must provide their App ID password.

Can the app being installed identify the Apple ID for the iPhone that the app is installed on?

If so, where is the API please?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid not, Apple is even phasing out iOS UDID access to solve privacy woes in iOS 5.